# JFileChooser Help

Tags: java, eclipse

I am attempting to make a program, and it involves a JFileChooser. I am trying to make it so that the users can only pick .zip files. My code is

```
JFileChooser finder = new JFileChooser();
finder.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter(null, ".zip"));
```

This seems to me like it would run fine, however when I go to a folder with a .zip file, the .zip files are gray, and I can't choose them. How do I fix this? Also, as a side question, how do I get rid of the "All Files" option in the JFileChooser window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `"zip"` as an extension filter, not `".zip"`.

Comment: Also, how do I get the name of the file without the .zip extension?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924394/how-to-get-file-name-without-the-extension

Comment: Thank you, but that thread talks about FilenameUtils which doesn't work with my version of Java/Eclipse. Eclipse just underlines it in red and there is no quickfix available. I have also tried importing the package that it comes from according to the thread, but that doesn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: How about the regex answer there?

Answer (score 10):

Yes just replace ".zip" with "zip" and also you can remove "All Files" option and make it as "Zip Files". Use following code for that...

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
// select only zip files and add "Zip Files" option
fileChooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Zip Files", "zip"));
// remove "All Files" option
fileChooser.removeChoosableFileFilter(fileChooser.getAcceptAllFileFilter());
```

Comment: I tried to use this code and it works fine, But in the field "Files of Type" I was expecting "*.txt" to appear, but it doesn't. How to show the user that what type of file is expected from them to choose?

Answer (score 1):

The extension for the `FileFilter` should not contain the dot.  The dot is the separator between the name and extention parts and not part of the extention.  Try it with just `zip` not `.zip`.  See the [javadoc for FileFilter for more.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileNameExtensionFilter.html)

```
finder.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter(null, "zip"));
```